Why does an X++ enum support 251 unique values (and not 256)?
The X++ documentation states that:

[Y]ou can declare up to 251 (0 to 250) literals in a single enum type

The number 251 seems a rather odd choice to me. Given its closeness to 256, my initial assumption would be that the values of an enum are stored as a byte under the hood, but that begs the question: Why not let us use all 256 bytes?

Before-first, after-last, null would still be too few special cases.

It's most likely for bitwise operations with masking. AX uses bit-shifting for various low-level things, and they are reserving the first 5 bits (0-31) for those masks, perhaps. Probably due to programming decisions super early on that they need to live with now.
A few things I can think of are layers (VAR/CUS/USR/etc.), some Table/Group/All operations, some inventory dimension things, and more that deal with bitshifting.
It could also be for container packing logic or avoiding byte boundary checks.
